# Set Akavache BlobCache storage path other than default path

Tags: c#-4.0, akavache

I have a requirement where I need to set the `BlobCache` path to other than default path's.

By default its saving under below paths

> C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\AkavacheApp\BlobCache
>
> C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\AkavacheApp\BlobCache

But I want it to be saved under different path like

> "D:\Data\AkavacheApp\BlobCache"

Please guide me how to do it in C#.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but sometimes the easiest thing are simply overlooked.

First of all, you can (and should) create your own blobs by

```
var blob = new SQLitePersistentBlobCache(path);
```

and

```
var blob = new SQLiteEncryptedBlobCache(path);
```

Those global variables are just for easy start with Aakavache.

Secondly, if all you need is for example to add a company name into the path, just set BlobCache.AppliactionName to "your company/app", since this is directly translated to path in BlobCache contructor in global variables.

Answer (score -3):

Akavache is open source, the source code can be found over on  GitHub at https://github.com/akavache/Akavache. You'll be able to figure out what you need to do by looking at the source code.